# Clarifai: Tag extraction from video

Tags: youtube, tags, clarifai

Does clarifai has the mechanism to extract tags from YouTube video?

If it is possible, Kindly let me know how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

No. Tag requests for video need to include a URL for a hosted video file. mp4, mkv, and a few other formats are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this site that offers face, emotion analysis in real time on video streams. I have tried their demo on any youtube video - http:/bit.ly/2g7ShS8